# In multiple tables, how to align columns again after variable-width columns?

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

There are multiple (e.g., 2) tables that contain similar information. Between them is one table row of white space.

All tables have 3 columns. The first two columns belong together, which is why the second column has no heading. There should be a `\qquad` of white space between the longest text in the first column and the leftmost character of the second column. (It's ok to seek out the longest text manually and add the `\qquad` manually, like below.)

Is there a nice way to align the third columns as illustrated below? It would be great if a solution existed without `\phantom` fiddling or breaking the table information totally  apart in the source.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}p{5cm}@{}|>{\raggedleft}p{1.5cm}@{}}
\textbf{Col1}            &                  & \textbf{Col3} \tabularnewline
Text1                    & Text1Description & 0.1  \tabularnewline
VerylongText2\qquad\null & Text2Description & 3    \tabularnewline
Text3                    & Text3Description & 2    \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\\
\\
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}p{5cm}@{}|>{\raggedleft}p{1.5cm}@{}}
\textbf{Col1}            &                  & \textbf{Col3} \tabularnewline
Text4                    & Text4Description & 3    \tabularnewline
LongText5\qquad\null     & Text5Description & 0.2  \tabularnewline
Text6                    & Text6Description & 0.34 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: are all the entries one-line or will some of the middle column entries wrap?

Comment: Every row fits in one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l|l@{}}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\quad}p{5cm}@{}}
\textbf{Col1}            &                  \tabularnewline
Text1                    & Text1Description \tabularnewline
VerylongText2            & Text2Description \tabularnewline
Text3                    & Text3Description 
\end{tabular}
&\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}                             
\textbf{Col3} \tabularnewline  
0.1  \tabularnewline           
3    \tabularnewline           
2
\end{tabular}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\quad}p{5cm}@{}}
\textbf{Col1}            &                  \tabularnewline
Text4                    & Text4Description \tabularnewline
LongText5                & Text5Description \tabularnewline
Text6                    & Text6Description 
\end{tabular}
&\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}                             
 \textbf{Col3} \tabularnewline   
 3    \tabularnewline            
 0.2  \tabularnewline            
 0.34 
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

alternatively with simpler markup but it takes a couple of runs to settle down:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\def\zz#1#2{%
\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{\gdef\string#1{\the\pdflastxpos sp}}%
\ifx\@undefined#1%
\else
\ifx\@undefined#2%
\else
\ifdim#2<#1\relax
\kern\dimexpr#2-#1\relax
\fi
\fi
\fi}


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\qquad}p{5cm}@{\zz\za\zb}|p{1.5cm}@{}}
\textbf{Col1}     &                  & \textbf{Col3} \tabularnewline
Text1             & Text1Description & 0.1  \tabularnewline
VerylongText2     & Text2Description & 3    \tabularnewline
Text3             & Text3Description & 2    \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\qquad}p{5cm}@{\zz\zb\za}|p{1.5cm}@{}}
\textbf{Col1}     &                  & \textbf{Col3} \tabularnewline
Text4             & Text4Description & 3    \tabularnewline
LongText5         & Text5Description & 0.2  \tabularnewline
Text6             & Text6Description & 0.34 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David. This is what I meant by "breaking the table information apart in the source". It makes validating and maintaining the data much harder. Sorry that my question wasn't more clear.

Comment: @FrankSeifert well the outer table in your question wasn't doing anything (it could just be removed) so I thought I'd put it to some use:-)

Comment: Fair enough. I like the improvements you did to the source. I hope there's a "nicer" way, or else I'll go with something like this.

Comment: @FrankSeifert, if you _really_ wanted data input in the original order I'd define the 3rd column of the inner table not to set its content but to just globally build up a macro adding `..cell contents..\tabularnewline` each time and then use that macro as the outer 3rd (2nd) column data. But to be honest I wouldn't bother doing that, especially not at this time of night..

Comment: @FrankSeifert I added a plan b:-)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, `\widthof` from the `calc` package can be used. (This is what I actually had in mind when I mentioned "`\phantom` fiddling" in my question.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\qquad}p{5cm}@{}|>{\raggedleft}p{1.5cm}@{}}
\textbf{Col1}     &                  & \textbf{Col3} \tabularnewline
Text1             & Text1Description & 0.1  \tabularnewline
VerylongText2     & Text2Description & 3    \tabularnewline
Text3             & Text3Description & 2    \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\\
\\
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\qquad}p{5cm+\widthof{VerylongText2}-\widthof{LongText5}}@{}|>{\raggedleft}p{1.5cm}@{}}
\textbf{Col1}     &                  & \textbf{Col3} \tabularnewline
Text4             & Text4Description & 3    \tabularnewline
LongText5         & Text5Description & 0.2  \tabularnewline
Text6             & Text6Description & 0.34 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```